# Build own form in Liferay

Tags: forms, liferay

How can I build my own form in Liferay? Do I need to first create a hook or portlet and then edit the files there or is there some framework or templates I could use for making a customized form? I just need steps how to approach this, no ready made solutions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dynamic Data Lists concept can help you on that.

Comment: I have managed to do this in liferay using maven and so far so good. Some way to get to the final result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking to have dynamic form and capturing/accessing data, Dynamic Data Lists or Web Form portlet can be helpful to you.

Please refer to Liferay's Documentation Link : [Using Web Forms and Dynamic Data Lists](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/using-web-forms-and-dynamic-data-lists-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-10-en)

Comment: Actually it is just a form where users registering for a service fill in their personal data and upon submit the form data is delivered to an email address.

Comment: Yes Web Form is similar to that but Dynamic Data List is not same. It stores data and you can get those data even

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. I am trying to see if DDL can do the job here.

Comment: DDL doesn't seem to be a good option for this purpose. I need to be able to send the data to an email, but this doesn't allow that.

Comment: you mean you want to preserve data as well as send to an email?

Comment: No I dont want to preserve any data. Once the customer fills the form, he/she submits the form data to my email. That's why I think DDL is not necessary to use here.

Comment: Then webform portlet can be used

Comment: I know there is the web form to use, but I need to edit that, I can't use it just as it is. The structure of this form I am going to create is totally different from Liferay's own web form. So if I want to take the web form as a basis and make a new customized form portlet out of it, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a portlet ( LiferayMVC or Spring-MVC ) using JSP, or you create an HTML form using UI taglibs  ...

Exemple:

```
<aui:form action="<%= myActionURL %>" method="post" name="myForm">
        <aui:input label="My Text Input" name="myTextInput" type="text" 
        value='<%= "My Text Value" %>' />

        <aui:button type="submit" />
</aui:form>
```

**Please refere to this link** : **[Liferay_HTML_Form](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/front-end-taglibs)**